# Relative sizes in Windows Store apps XAML pages

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I want to set a grid at 30% the screen height, its height being the 20% of the screen height. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and I would like to set this directly in the XAML.

Is this possible?
Or I have to change sizes from the program, at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer Grid with appropriate column and row definitions:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="White">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```